# Is there any other method of showing that sets $A$ and $B$ are equal without showing that $A \subseteq B$ and $B \subseteq A$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

As an example, we can let $A = \{(a,0) \in \mathbb{F}^2 : a \in \mathbb{F}\}$ and $B = \{ (0,b) \in \mathbb{F}^2 : b \in \mathbb{F} \}$. If we define $$\sum_{i=1}^n X_i = \left\{ \sum_{i=1}^n x_i : x_i \in X_i \right\}$$ and wish to show that $A + B = \{ (a,b)) : a,b \in \mathbb{F} \} = C$, then one would begin by showing $A + B \subseteq C$ and then by showing that $C \subseteq A + B$. This process would typically look something like letting $x \in A+B$ and showing that is an element of $C$, and then letting $y \in C$ and showing that it is an element of $A+B$. However, this leads me to my question:

It is the standard way to prove two sets are equal, but are there any other ways to do so?

And of course, I am not referring to “obvious” cases where $A = \{ 1 \}$ and $B = \{ 1 \}$, so $A = B$ is clear just by observation.

Comment: Another method is to introduce a third set, $S$, and show that $A$ and $B$ both equal $S$.

Comment: I suppose one very slightly different approach in the case where $A$ and $B$ are finite would be to show that $A\subseteq B$ and $|A|=|B|$. If $A$ and $B$ have additional structure, there would be more options. For example, for finite groups one could prove $A\leq B$ and $|A| > |B|/2$ (or replace 2 with the smallest divisor of $|B|$ greater than 1); for vector spaces, one could prove $A\subseteq B$ and $\dim A = \dim B$.

Comment: @KenanskiBowspleefi The example of vector spaces only works for finite dimension.

Comment: Depending on how the sets are defined you may be capable of proving $x \in X\iff x\in Y$ and if you prove that then we'd have proven $X=Y$.

Comment: There are all sorts of theorems you can use in specific cases. Arguably it always comes down to showing $A \subseteq B$ and $B \subseteq A$, because this is pretty much how equality of sets is defined. One example is you can show $A = \Bbb N$ iff $0 \in A$ and whenever $n \in A$, we have $n + 1 \in A$ (AKA, proof by induction).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alternatively, you can apply the following result:

**Claim**

Given two sets $X$ and $Y$, we say that $X\subseteq Y$ iff $X\cap Y = X$.

Similarly, given two sets $X$ and $Y$, we say that $X\subseteq Y$ iff $X\cup Y = Y$.

**Comment**

If you are interested in proving that $X = Y$, you can apply the proposed claim above twice.